# Detect MediaStream pause on safari

Tags: javascript, webrtc

So there is this option on Safari both on desktop and mobile where you can "Pause" your camera and microphone feed.

[image: A screenshot of a dropdown menu in Safari browser showing active camera options]

It's different from other browsers where you just revoke previously given access, as it doesn't change or trigger anything on the media stream whatsoever. It replaced the camera feed with a black screen and then turns off the camera on the device.

So `track.onended` doesn't trigger, `MediaStreamTrack.readyState` stays `"live"`, `stream.active` return `true` etc.

I need this to trigger a warning or to end a webRTC video call if the client is trying to bypass the requirements of an active camera by pausing the camera feed after the initial setup.

**So my question**: is there an elegant way of detecting the "Safari pause" or my only option is to do some guestimating with image processing to detect a "black screen"? And if it's the latter I wouldn't mind a reference to some resources on how to achieve that.

***Edit**: I would like to catch the disabled camera clients before the webRTC call starts, so using bitrate to determine if the camera is active would be my last resort.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `muted` property on a `MediaStreamTrack` to check if it is "paused" in Safari.

```js
const tracks = mediaStream.getTracks();

for (const track of tracks) {
    console.log(track.muted);
}
```

There is also a `mute` and `unmute` event dispatched whenever the `muted` property changes.

Comment: That works perfectly! I feel silly skipping "mute" properties and events while sifting through docs as I assumed that is for audio tracks only. Not to mention that this works perfectly with a "mute mic" feature that toggles `.enabled` on the audio track - in a sense that it doesn't trigger for that.

Comment: I agree that the naming is very confusing. I guess the reason for that is the classic "for historic reasons".